# Extract Video ID to Youtube URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with an input to put a **Youtube link**.
I automatically replace the link with the **ID of the video**, no worries until then.

But I encounter a problem when I want a preview of the id below, i get `?v=f` and `f`.

The problem is that I would only like the ID and then put it in an `<iframe>`

```js
$('.youtube_url').on('change', function (){

        var newval = '',
            $this = $(this);

        if (newval = $this.val().match(/(\?|&)v=([^&#]+)/)) {

            $this.val(newval.pop());

        } else if (newval = $this.val().match(/(\.be\/)+([^\/]+)/)) {

            $this.val(newval.pop());

        } else if (newval = $this.val().match(/(\embed\/)+([^\/]+)/)) {

            $this.val(newval.pop().replace('?rel=0',''));
        }
        $('#preview').html(newval);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="youtube-id">Youtube URL:</label>
<input id="youtube-id" type="text" class="youtube_url">
<div id="preview"></div>

<p>URL for test : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTNBRS8ZS4U
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

javascript `match()` doesn't return what you think it does:

> If the string matches the expression, it will return an Array containing the entire matched string as the first element, followed by any results captured in parentheses. If there were no matches, null is returned.

So `'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTNBRS8ZS4U'.match(/(\?|&)v=([^&#]+)/)` returns the array:

```
["?v=dTNBRS8ZS4U", "?", "dTNBRS8ZS4U"]
```

That is, the full part of the matched string, and then the first and second captured bits.

You then immediately pop() the final element, `dTNBRS8ZS4U`, and place that back into the input field. All good.

But then you preview the **updated** contents of the newval array. Since you pulled the final element already, newval now is:

```
["?v=dTNBRS8ZS4U", "?"]
```

Which is what you're get for your preview. The solution would involve saving what is pop()'d and putting **that** in the preview.